# how to check all fields in the array contains data

Tags: ios, swift, loops

I want to check the array to see if all the fields have a value, and if all the fields have a value, then I want it to do something. My code does work but it is really messy. I'd like to know if there is an easier way of doing this.

```
@IBAction func testBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
          self.textData = arrayCellsTextFields.valueForKey("text") as! [String]

    for item in textData {
        if item.isEmpty {


        print("Missing")
            switchKey = true
          // alertviewer will go here
        break


        } else {

        switchKey = false
        }
    }

    if switchKey == false {
        //navigation here
        print("done")

    }

}
```

Comment: Show the log of textData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this combination of `guard` and `.filter`:

```
@IBAction func testBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.textData = arrayCellsTextFields.valueForKey("text") as! [String]
    guard textData.count == (textData.filter { !$0.isEmpty }).count else {
        print("Missing")
        return
    }
    print("Done")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the `filter`function

```
if textData.filter({$0.isEmpty}).count > 0 {
  // there is at least one empty item
} else {
  // all items contain data
}
```